# Why does Python `pip list` need `--no-index` option?

Tags: python, pip

I understand why one cares about `--no-index` option with `pip install`.

Why is this option present for `pip list`?

I thought that `pip list` only works with local installaton. What does it have to do with the package index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pip list`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_list/) can do things like list all outdated packages. From the examples:

```
$ pip list --outdated
docutils (Current: 0.10 Latest: 0.11)
Sphinx (Current: 1.2.1 Latest: 1.2.2)
```

There's no way to do that without comparing the installed package version to the repo package version, which means `pip list` potentially needs to access the same data as `pip install`.

Comment: Thanks! I forgot about `--outdated`.